# Como pasar una variable de una pagina html a otra despues de recibir una peticion get con axios? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, axios, tablas

Tengo una tabla con 4 columnas y quiero que cuando le de click a una de ellas me aparezca un icono hacia abajo y los datos de la columna se ordenen, el unico gran problema es que cuando le doy click y hago la peticion que se recarga la pagina el icono no se actualiza, que puedo hacer?

necesito que cuando de click en una de las columnas haga una peticion y en la url aparezca '?ordering=t1' y el icono de la flecha hacia abajo y si le doy click nuevamente haga otra peticion pero esta vez con '?ordering=-t1' y la flecha hacia arriba.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th class="toggleCelda1">
      <div class="text "><span>USERNAME<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno"></i></span></div>

    </th>
    <th class="toggleCelda2">
      <div class="text"><span>Total 1<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno"></i></span></div>

    </th>
    <th class="toggleCelda3">
      <div class="text"><span>Total 2<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno"></i></span></div>

    </th>
    <th class="toggleCelda4">
      <div class="text"><span>Total 3<i class="fas fa-sort" id="uno"></i></span></div>

    </th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for c in summary %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ c.user }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.num_calls1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.num_calls2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ c.num_calls3 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var toggleCelda1 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda1');
  var toggleCelda2 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda2');
  var toggleCelda3 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda3');
  var toggleCelda4 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda4');
  var toggleIconCelda1 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda1 i')
  var toggleIconCelda2 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda2 i')
  var toggleIconCelda3 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda3 i')
  var toggleIconCelda4 = document.querySelector('.toggleCelda4 i')



  function datos(order) {

    axios.get(order)
      .then(response => {


      })
  }



  function ordenar(IconCelda, OrderType) {



    if (IconCelda.classList.contains('fa-sort')) {

      datos('?ordering=t' + OrderType + '&', )
      IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort-down iconshow')

    } else if (IconCelda.classList.contains('fa-sort-down')) {

      IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort-up iconshow')
      datos('?ordering=-t' + OrderType + '&')

    } else {

      IconCelda.setAttribute('class', 'fas fa-sort')
      datos('?ordering=t' + OrderType + '&')
    }


  }


  toggleCelda1.addEventListener('click', function () {

    ordenar(toggleIconCelda1, 1)


  })

  toggleCelda2.addEventListener('click', function () {

    ordenar(toggleIconCelda2, 2)

  })

  toggleCelda3.addEventListener('click', function () {

    ordenar(toggleIconCelda3, 3)

  });

  toggleCelda4.addEventListener('click', function () {

    ordenar(toggleIconCelda4, 4)

  });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir lo que has intentado al momento? Mira [ask], ahí verás que puedes incluir lo que te comento a modo de un [mcve], puedes hacerlo en cualquier momento haciendo clic sobre el botón de [edit]. También te invito a relizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: ya agregue el codigo que he logrado hacer hasta ahora

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar redirigir al usuario a la misma URL, pero con otro parámetro, y allá procesar el orden, por ejemplo (suponiendo que la página actual se muestra en `http://misitio.com/mipagina`):

```
toggleCelda1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location.href="http://misitio.com/mipagina?ordering=t1";
});
```

Ahora, cuando la página cargue, lo primero que debes hacer es revisar ese parámetro y obtener los datos basado en ese orden, algo como:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const ordering = params.get("ordering"); //t1
//y aqui puede llamar a tu funcion para obtener los datos en ese orden
//datos(ordering)
```

Basado en esto, ya puedes mostrar los iconos de la tabla como quieras.

Asi, cada que des click en una columna, la página se va a recargar y cargara los datos como los necesita... o si lo recargas manual tambien, porque el orden viene establecido desde la URL.